Hide markers in subplot with button
I would like to hide the markers in a subplot.
Is this possible?
MRE:
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
n = 100
x, y, z = np.random.rand(3, n)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, 
                    specs=[[{'type': 'scatter'}, {'type': 'scatter'}]]
                    )

# Scatter plot with markers
fig.add_trace(
go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color='red',
        opacity=0.8
    ),
    name='m'
),
row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
 go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color='red',
        opacity=0.8
    ),
    name='m2'
), row=1, col=2)



button = dict(
    method='restyle',
    args=[{"mode": "lines+markers", 'marker.size': 0}],  
    label='Remove Markers'
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{
        'buttons': [button],
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True,
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'left',
        'y': 1.1,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }]
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()

On my machine, this removes the marker from the legend but not the plot. What am I doing wrong?
How can I remove only the markers on the left subplot and keep the ones on the right subplot?

Your purpose is a bit unclear. If it is to not show the graph on the left, then change to the following settings. button = dict(     method='restyle',     args=[{"visible": [False, True], 'showlegend': True}],       label='Remove Markers' )  Please add a more detailed explanation if my understanding is incorrect.

visible is not a good option. The plot needs to be there, but without markers. The one on the right should have markers.

You just need to switch the drawing mode  :
button1 = dict(
    method='restyle',
    args=[{"mode": "lines+markers"}, [0]],
    label='Show Markers'
)

button2 = dict(
    method='restyle',
    args=[{"mode": "lines"}, [0]],
    label='Remove Markers'
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[{
        'buttons': [button1, button2],
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True,
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'left',
        'y': 1.1,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }]
)

fig.show()

